# how to insert data from textboxes to datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, textbox, insert

I have a task i.e i have to insert data from text boxes to datagridview and then save the   datagridview data into database with multiple rows what i added from text boxes to datagridview.i tried some code but it is working for first row only i cont add more than one row.can any one help me how can i do this?.

```
  private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dgvUom.Rows[0].Cells["UomType"].Value = txtUomtyp.Text;
        dgvUom.Rows[0].Cells["UOmDesc"].Value = txtUomDesc.Text;
    }
```

Comment: how is your `dataGridView` looks like and how many columns?

Comment: Are the textboxes outside the datagridview ? or are embedded inside the gridview ? and your solution is working for the first row, because you are only doing it for the first row. dgvUom.Rows[0] <-- it represents your first row.

Comment: my textboxes are out side the dgv ,and my dgv have two colums only

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string firstColum = txtUomtyp.Text;
        string secondColum = txtUomDesc.Text;
        string[] row = { firstColum, secondColum };
        dgvUom.Rows.Add(row);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome .. keep it up and practice hard `:D`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you which worked for me

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = (DataTable)dgvUom.DataSource;
    string firstColumn = txtUomtyp.Text;
    string secondColumn = cbxVNo.Text;
    string[] row = { firstColumn, secondColumn };
    dGVInventory.Rows.Add(row);
```